# Dash not getting updated

Tags: python, pandas

I am running the below code the output is even coming but the issue is that i have to run the file again and again to get the output in juypter note book but as per code it should automatically update

**Code**:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
%matplotlib inline

data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Adnan\Desktop\OldFaithful.csv")
count=0
x=[]
y=[]

def draw_graph(i):
    global count
    count +=1
    x.append(count)
    y.append(data['Y'][count])
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x,y)

anima= animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(),draw_graph,interval=1500)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the dataset?

Comment: I did not get what u said could you please elaboate

Comment: Can you share an `OldFaithful.csv`?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mXDRksICxHmBTF3Pa1I5BoBwpXuaMqpifBhBmWiT9AM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need something like this?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc
%matplotlib inline

data=pd.read_csv("OldFaithful.csv.txt")
data.head(3)
data = np.array([np.arange(data.shape[0]), data.iloc[:, 1]])

def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[:, :num])
    return line,

fig1 = plt.figure()

l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 220)
plt.ylim(42, 95)
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, data.shape[1], fargs=(data, l), interval=50)
rc('animation', html='jshtml')
line_ani
```

Comment: Hi Yoskutik thanks a tone now i will try to take data from my sql server and try the same can you help me out how to increase the space between the two line that is being generated as the lines are coming very close to each other

Comment: You can set `figsize` in `fig1 = plt.figure()`. For example, `fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[15, 8])`. Also, if you think the answer is correct, please mark it

Comment: Hi Yoskutik, Now i want to connect the same with sql management studio and pic the data from that i have the below code let me know how will i call the say Team1 and Date time as x and y axis receptively

Answer (score 0):

Code:

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
 server='LAPTOP-OO3V36UA\SQLEXPRESS'
db='addy'

conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=' +server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_connection=yes')

sql="""

SELECT * FROM Summry

"""
df=pd.read_sql(sql ,conn)
df

output
   Team1    Team2   Team3   Team4   Dateandtime
50  70  90  77  2020-05-27 16:11:35.683
30  80  60  70  2020-05-27 16:11:54.467
65  95  120 90  2020-05-27 16:12:12.793
195 100 220 300 2020-05-27 16:12:30.530
180 80  20  200 2020-05-27 16:12:51.297